# How to get the complete HTML document when using Mechanize

Tags: ruby

I have been trying to scrape a page with Mechanize using:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
doc = agent.get("SomeURL").parser
```

It does not return the whole document and the part that I need to get info from is not shown. How can I force Mechanize to give me the complete document?

Comment: We don't have enough information to help you. If it doesn't return the whole document, what does it return? What part is missing? Please be specific.

Comment: Use `wget`, `curl` or `nokogiri` at the command-line to retrieve the document then look to see if the data is there. Odds are good the document has DHTML and content is being loaded by the browser after the document is parsed. Mechanize can't help you in that case, you'll need something that interprets JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
agent = Mechanize.new
doc = agent.get("SomeURL")
doc.body
```

Comment: It's always better to include some explanation rather than just having a code-only answer as that makes it more useful to future readers.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593) (Note: I'm not familiar with this domain, so this answer may actually be simple enough to make an explanation, and thus downvotes, unnecessary. You may still want to add an explanation to prevent more NAA/VLQ flags.)